# Embroidery on crochet afghan

Tags: crocheting, embroidery

I don’t know anything about embroidery, but would really like to start applying embroidery detail onto my crochet afghans. I have some questions as to what would make this most effective.

1. What crochet stitch would work best if I’d want to embroider on it? Hook and yarn size would be good to know too.
2. Is it then possible to apply embroidery onto the yarn? What equipment would I need to do this?

I have here a picture of the type of embroidery I would like to do on the afghan. Also, some kind of lettering would be a nice addition.

[image]

Comment: Hi Leandri, if you don't know anything about embroidery yet, this might not be the best platform to ask: we focus on specific problems, and don't really write full tutorials. On that note, please take the [Tour] to familiarize yourself with this platform. If you do have some knowledge about sewing, please edit it into your post and focus your question. Welcome to Arts & Crafts!

Comment: @joachim thanks for letting me know. I’m not really looking for a full how-to tutorial here, but rather advice on what I do consider a single, focused problem/question.

Answer (score 3):

Just a few thoughts:

- Embroidery is usually done on a plain canvas. If the background has too much of a pattern, the embroidery will simply fade into the background. You'll want a very plain and even crochet stitch for the afghan.
- Use unicolor yarn for the afghan or the embroidery might fade into the background.
- If you'd like the afghan to have more of a pattern (like granny squares), insert a patch of very plain stitches where the embroidery is going to be.
- Embroidery is not stretchy at all. You'll want a crocheted background that is not stretchy as well. Look for "opaque" crochet patterns for some inspiration.
- Don't forget to crochet some test swathes to see how a pattern turns out and if you like it. This is also the best way to assess the stretchyness of the pattern and to compare different patterns.

The yarn size depends on your personal preference and the hook size depends on the yarn size and how tight you want to crochet the pattern. As a rule of thumb, thicker yarn means you crochet faster, but very loosely spun yarn can rip and tear faster once the afghan is finished and in use (this is especially important if you have kids or pets).

Embroidery is also a very broad topic... there are so many techniques that are all called "embroidery".

- Use a yarn that has a contrasting color to the afghan.
- The yarn should be at least as thick as the one you used for the afghan.
- To make the embroidery more obvious, you could embroider with 2 strings of yarn at the same time. That makes the lines thicker without doubling the number of stitches you have to do.
- The example in your question is not done 100% with yarn alone, it has patches of (what looks like) felt stitched onto the canvas.